# RedirectToLocal role wise redirection in identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity, roles

Having issues while login with different role, any effective way to use the role to redirection role wise page ?

```
 private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)

     {

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Role");
            }                
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");            
    }
```

Comment: Sorry! What is the problem you are facing and what is your expected behavior ?

Comment: I want to redirect to the admin page if role is match to "admin" neither redirected to home, if role is "user" then redirect to user home. Actually i mean to say that role Wise login redirection page ( identity).